# mean stack yo generator gives error when creating a new app

Tags: node.js, macos, mean, yeoman-generator

I am using mac OSx yosemit and I have installed bitnami mean stack package.
when i want to create a new app using generator it gives an error about v8-debugger.
Here are steps;

```
 1. sudo npm install -g yo
 2. npm install -g generator-meanjs
 3. mkdir test & cd test/
 4. yo meanjs
```

this asks me some questions about app and then starts to install required packages. It end with following error

```
 > v8-profiler@5.2.12 install /Users/tahir/Developer/mean_stack/yo_app/node_modules/grunt-node-inspector/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/v8-profiler
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

[v8-profiler] Success: "/Users/tahir/Developer/mean_stack/yo_app/node_modules/grunt-node-inspector/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/v8-profiler/build/profiler/v5.2.12/node-v14-darwin-x64/profiler.node" is installed via remote
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/Applications/meanstack-3.0.4-2/nodejs/bin/.node.bin" "/Applications/meanstack-3.0.4-2/nodejs/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! v8-debug@0.4.6 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the v8-debug@0.4.6 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the v8-debug package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls v8-debug
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/tahir/Developer/mean_stack/yo_app/npm-debug.log
```

I can't figure out what is problem I referred to some solutions like a discussion here https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/662 but unable to solve this issue. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Suggestion: Reinstall node and python 2.7 and try again.

Comment: @shan1024 thanks for suggestion, i will give it a try.

Comment: Why the downvote on this question, I have the same issue on mac 10.9.5 with a clean and latest node installation !

Comment: thanx @LucDUZAN. This issue is usually encountered by my team members as well. And mostly it is sorted by hit and trail method.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "hit and trail method" ?

Comment: @Luc DUZAN if search for solution you will find different solutions like update you CLI tools, Reinstall you Xcode and CLI tools and some other as well. So sometimes it could be solved only updating tools and sometimes doing both or even some other trick to play with. I am still not able to configure what is exact problem and who is responsible for this issue.